# How to compare two json objects using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have two json objects

```
 $scope.car1={"Sedan":{"Audi":["A4","A3"]},"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]}}; 
  $scope.car2={"Hatchback":{"Maruthi":["Swift"]},"Sedan":{"Audi":["A3","A4"]}};
```

I want to compare these two objects. I tried the following code:

```
var a=angular.equals($scope.car1,$scope.car2);
```

Since `angular.equals`do  a deep comparison it also care about the order of data. Is there any way to compare objects regardless of the order?

Answer (score 2):

'Objects' do not have an order. `angular.equals` will compare values using their keys.

Comment: The 'Sedan' key's value 'Audi' has different arrays (the order is different in these arrays).

Comment: Well, technically, Tarun, you are right, but still this is his question: put, given two arrays, how can i compare them order-less (note: recursively)

Comment: ok, I was under the assumption that he was comparing objects not arrays. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom "recursive equalizer" that distinct if array is associative or not:
for associative => equalize keys,
for arrays => sort array & equalize elements.

written the function `myEqual()` [at this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBOG39JA4IFeydWvBzxV?p=preview)

Comment: I don't need to use underscore.js in this case. I need pure javascript or angularjs.

Comment: well, you can easily implement another one,
i'll post some code later when i find the time.

Comment: there are no associative arrays in javascript